# Does the residuals distrubution change the result of least-squares estimation?

Tags: least-squares, nonlinear-regression

Suppose I have the model: $\mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\theta})+\mathbf{e}$ where $f$ is a nonlinear function, $\theta$ a parameter vector, $\mathbf{x}$ the independent variable vector and $\mathbf{e}$ the residuals vector ($\mathbf{y}$, you guessed, is the observations vector).

Does the residuals' distribution matter when trying to find $\mathbf{\theta}$ using a nonlinear least-squares approach (like Levenberg-Marquardt for unconstrained case or trust-region-reflective for the constrained case)?

For linear least-squares I think it does not matter because no assumptions on the residuals' distribution are made but for the nonlinear least-squares I expect it to be the same but since I don't really know how the algorithms work I can't be sure!

Comment: In the linear case by the Gauss-Markov theorem, the least squares estimator is best linear unbiased where best means lowest variance.  Now there are assumptions on the residuals.  They must have 0 mean and be uncorrelated with common finite variance.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Ok with that. Suppose now I have no assumption on the residuals and moreover I have a nonlinear model. What I want to know is whether the residuals' distribution affects the solution of the nonlinear least-squares (trust region algorithms) or not.

Comment: @MichaelChernick My concern is that I did some assumptions on the residuals' distribution and I computed a nonlinear least-squares solution. Now I'm wondering what will change in my solution if I change the residual distribution.